# Use sourcetree to clone url from azureDevOps

Tags: atlassian-sourcetree

I want to use sourcetree to clone from azureDevOps

```
azureDevOps
I click copy clone URL to clipboard

Sourcetree
New => Clone from URL
and Paste https://xxxxx.visualstudio.com/xxxxx/_git/XXXXX (from my copy)
```

it say This is not a valid source path/URL

```
Details
abort: 'https://xxxxx.visualstudio.com/xxxxx/_git/XXXXX' does not appear to be an hg repository:

svn: E170013: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'https://xxxxx.visualstudio.com/xxxxx/_git/xxxxxx'
svn: E230001: Server SSL certificate verification failed: issuer is not trusted
```

if I want to login accounts (use sourcetree accounts)

Host  Azure DevOps https://xxxxxx.visualstudio.com/
login error 
couldn't connect
Check my username and password

but I can login and logout Azure DevOps with my username and password
so I don't know why login error

Answer (score 0):

The valid link to clone is

`https://{Organization}@dev.azure.com/{Organization}/{Project}/_git/{RepoName}`